# SQL query is not retrieving all the fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to tables in my database, the first one (participants) look just like that:

[image]

And I have another called votes in which I can vote for any participants.

[image]

So my problem is that I'm trying to get all the votes of each participant but when I execute my query it only retrieves four rows sorted by the COUNT of votes, And the other remaining are not appearing in my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `votes`.`id`) AS count_id, participants.name 
AS participant_name FROM `participants` LEFT OUTER JOIN `votes` ON
`votes`.`participant_id` = `participants`.`id` GROUP BY votes.participant_id ORDER BY
votes.participant_id DESC;
```

Retrieves:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure there are more `participant_name`s?

Comment: can you show us all rows (data) of your participant table

Comment: Yes, sure, I have 6 participants in my table(it could be more than 6) and there are only 3 participants that have votes, the other 3 are in 0 but why is not showing at least in 0 the other two is my question.

Comment: Can you try it without the distinct?

Comment: Updated! jtseng: I already try it and the same result only 4 rows when it should be 6 rows.

Comment: please try this and see if it shows all participants : SELECT * FROM `participants` LEFT OUTER JOIN `votes` ON `votes`.`participant_id` = `participants`.`id`

Comment: medBo: Yes it shows all the 6 participants.

Comment: @Andres Have you tried my query statement? Do they have the same output with your query and mine?

Comment: Your usage of `group by` is invalid SQL but sadly MySQL prefers to return random data instead of rejecting the statement (as every other DBMS does). Please read this for more details: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're grouping by `votes.participant_id`, rather than `participants.id`, which limits you to participants with votes, the `outer join` notwithstanding.  Check out http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5d3d/5/0

Comment: Exactly that was the problem, I just change in the GROUP BY part votes.participant_id TO participants.id

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As what i have understood from the query you gave you were selecting unique id's from the votes table and I assume that your column id is not an identity. but it would be better if that would be an identity? and if so, here is my answer.replace your select with these.

```
Select count (votes.participant.id) as count_id ,participants.name as participant_name 
from participants join votes
on participants.id = vote.participant_id
group by participants.name
order by count_id
```

just let me know if it works 
cheers

Comment: @Andres Have you try my query statement? :)